# Waffle authentication error

Tags: single-sign-on, waffle

When doing windows authentication using waffle api i am getting this error

"waffle.servlet.NegotiateSecurityFilter : error logging in user: The token supplied to the function is invalid"

Not sure why.

Comment: Did you solve it?